# How do I use Lua as data storage in IOS game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, lua, kobold2d

I've seen in some various IOS games Lua scripts being used for saving user settings, and data.  I can't figure out how to do this myself, does anyone know of an open source project or example of how to achieve this?

Are people just re-writing the lua scripts programatically? Or is there some way in Lua to rewrite or save data in a lua script? I'm really confused on how this is achieved with lua. Please help me out!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to serialize data, like save files, that can be read back later, is that correct? You may want to look [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are people just re-writing the lua scripts programatically?

Yes, it's really very simple. You store your setting data or whatever in a table. You then write that table to a file using simple Lua code. The file you write is a Lua script that, when executed, *returns the table.*

So your script looks like this:

```
return
{
  setting = true,
  width = 640,
  height = 480,
}
```

The code needed to write such serialization is not difficult to write (so long as you don't have tables referencing themselves, directly or indirectly). There are a [variety of implementations of this.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization)

Comment: So if I wanted a human readable file, that I could edit manually when necessary, I could use for example this one on the website: SaveTableToFile - save table to file/str; load table from file/str And it would simply dump the table into a file, including the name of variable and data?